# OpenLayer Icon user free transform

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my app I wrote an ol.interaction.Draw code that allow me to draw, rotate and scale proportionally an icon on a map view. After drawing the icon I can still scale it (but unfortunately I can't rotate it anymore) and drag and drop on the map but this process is not so much user friendly (e.g. it is difficult to understand where to position the mouse on the icon so to scale it/drag and drop).

So I need to emulate on my app the "Photoshop Ctrl+T" behavior:
so clicking  on my icon (or maybe with a key combination), it should appear all around a kind of rectangle that can allow me to rotate the icon, edit the base and high or scale proportionally (and of course this rectangle should disappear when I finish the editing). It would be possible and if yes how I can develope something like that?

This is my current code:

```js
initMap: function () {
           
            var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
            var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
            var width = 3;

            map = this.map;

            this.features = new ol.Collection();

            
            styles = [
              new ol.style.Style({

                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                  radius: width * 2,

                  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                     color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
                  }),
                }),
              }),
            ];

            var treeStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                   src: 'https://www.mikenunn.net/data/oak-tree-icon-png-17.png',
                }),
            });

            styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
                if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {
                    treeStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
                    treeStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
                    treeStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/(150*resolution));
                    return treeStyle;
                } else {
                   return styles;
                }
            }

            featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    features: this.features,
                    wrapX: false
                }),
                style: styleFunction
            });
            featureOverlay.setMap(map);

           

            this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features: this.features,
                type: 'Circle',
                geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
                    var center = coordinates[0];
                    var last = coordinates[1];
                    var dx = center[0] - last[0];
                    var dy = center[1] - last[1];
                    var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    var rotation = Math.PI - Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                    geometry = geometry || new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
                    geometry.setCenter(center);
                    geometry.setRadius(radius);
                    geometry.set('rotation', rotation);
                    return new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
                },
                style: styleFunction,
                handler: 'onSaveClick'
            });

            this.draw.on('drawstart', function () {
                        this.features.clear();
                    }, this);

            this.map.addInteraction(this.draw);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a pointermove select interaction with a style which shows the circle and its center will highlight where to use the modify interaction

```
  var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
  var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
  var width = 3;

  var pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: width * 2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
      })
    }),
    zIndex: Infinity
  });

  var selectStyles = [
      new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
         })
      }),
      new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: white,
              width: width + 2
          })
      }),
      new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: blue,
              width: width
          })
      }),
      florplanStyle,
      pointStyle
  ];

  selectStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
      if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {
          pointStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
          florplanStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
          florplanStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
          florplanStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/(150*resolution));
          return selectStyles;
      } else {
          return styles;
      }
   }

   map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
       condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
       features: this.features,
       style: selectStyleFunction
   }));
```

There seems to be a problem using select and draw interactions together with a features collection.  It does work linking them to a source

```
        source = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: this.features,
            wrapX: false
        }),

        featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source,
            style: styleFunction
        });

        this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: source,
            type: 'Circle',
            ....

        this.draw.on('drawstart', function () {
                    source.clear();
                }, this);

        map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
            condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
            source: source,
            style: selectStyleFunction
        }));
```

Rotation and displaying rectangular geometry would need a custom interaction.  Luckily the ol-ext Transform interaction https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.transform.html seems to do everything you need.  The rotation will need to be moved from the geometry to the feature before the interaction can be used, that can be done on the drawend, and the style updated to use rotation from either.  There's currently a strange effect if you rotate a circle feature, which I have patched in the snippet, but I have informed the ol-ext developer of the issue so hopefully that won't be need if he fixes it.

```js
// Patch because ol-ext is changing extent of circle during rotation
ol.geom.Circle.prototype.rotate = function(){};

var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
var width = 3;
styles = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: white,
      width: width + 2
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: blue,
      width: width
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: width * 2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
      })
    }),
    zIndex: Infinity
  })
];

var treeStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
       src: 'https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/oak-tree-icon-png-17.png'
    })
});

styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {
        treeStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
        // get rotation from drawn feature or geometry
        treeStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.get('rotation') || feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
        treeStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/(150*resolution));
        return treeStyle;
    } else {
       return styles;
    } 
}

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var features = new ol.Collection();

var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false, features: features});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
    })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Circle',
    geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
        var center = coordinates[0];
        var last = coordinates[1];
        var dx = center[0] - last[0];
        var dy = center[1] - last[1];
        var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var rotation = Math.PI - Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        geometry = geometry || new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
        geometry.setCenterAndRadius(center, radius);
        geometry.set('rotation', rotation);
        return geometry;
    },
    style: styleFunction
});

draw.on('drawstart', function () {
    //source.clear();
});

draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
    // move rotation from geometry to drawn feature
    evt.feature.set('rotation', evt.feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
    evt.feature.getGeometry().unset('rotation');
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

var modify = new ol.interaction.Transform({
    features: features
});

var startangle = 0;

modify.on('rotatestart', function(e) {
    startangle = e.feature.get('rotation') || 0;
});

modify.on('rotating', function (e) {
    // Set angle attribute to be used on style !
    e.feature.set('rotation', startangle - e.angle);
});

modify.on('select', function(e) {
    draw.setActive(e.features.length == 0);
});

map.addInteraction(modify);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Example of dynamically creating scaled icons (bounding polygons shown to help debugging):

```js
// Patch because ol-ext is changing extent of circle during rotation
ol.geom.Circle.prototype.rotate = function(angle, anchor){
    var point = new ol.geom.Point(this.getCenter());
    point.rotate(angle, anchor);
    this.setCenter(point.getCoordinates());
};

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://www.mikenunn.net/data/oak-tree-icon-png-17.png';

function getImage(img, scaleX, scaleY) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var x = Math.round(img.width * scaleX);
    var y = Math.round(img.height * scaleY);
    canvas.width = x;
    canvas.height = y;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, x, y);
    var url = canvas.toDataURL();
    canvas.remove();
    return url;
}

var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
var width = 3;
styles = [
  new ol.style.Style({
   //     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
   //       color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
   //     })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: white,
      width: width + 2
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: blue,
      width: width
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: width * 2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
      })
    }),
    zIndex: Infinity
  })
];

var treeStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
       src: img.src
    })
});

styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var resAdjust = 150 * resolution;
    var rotation = feature.get('rotation');
    if (rotation !== undefined) {

        var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        var tl = coordinates[0];
        var bl = coordinates[1];
        var br = coordinates[2];
        var tr = coordinates[3];

        var center = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);
        var top = new ol.geom.LineString([tl, tr]).getClosestPoint(center);
        var left = new ol.geom.LineString([tl, bl]).getClosestPoint(center);

        var dx = center[0] - left[0];
        var dy = center[1] - left[1];
        var scaleX = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)/resAdjust;

        var dx = top[0] - center[0];
        var dy = top[1] - center[1];
        var scaleY = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)/resAdjust;

        var treeStyle2 = new ol.style.Style({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(center),
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
               src: getImage(img, scaleX, scaleY),
               rotation: rotation
            })
        });
        return styles.concat([treeStyle2]);

    } else if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {
        treeStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
        // get rotation from drawn feature or geometry
        treeStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
        treeStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/resAdjust);
        return treeStyle;
    } else {
       return styles;
    } 
}

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var features = new ol.Collection();

var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false, features: features});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
    })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Circle',
    geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
        var center = coordinates[0];
        var last = coordinates[1];
        var dx = center[0] - last[0];
        var dy = center[1] - last[1];
        var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var rotation = Math.PI - Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        geometry = geometry || new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
        geometry.setCenterAndRadius(center, radius);
        geometry.set('rotation', rotation);
        return geometry;
    },
    style: styleFunction
});

draw.on('drawstart', function () {
    //source.clear();
});

draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
    // move rotation from geometry to drawn feature
    var rotation = evt.feature.getGeometry().get('rotation');
    evt.feature.set('rotation', rotation);
    var geom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(evt.feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
    geom.rotate(-rotation, evt.feature.getGeometry().getCenter());
    evt.feature.setGeometry(geom);
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

var modify = new ol.interaction.Transform({
    features: features,
    translateFeature: false,
    // flip wouldn't be compatible with rotation
    noFlip: true 
});

var startangle = 0;

modify.on('rotatestart', function(e) {
    startangle = e.feature.get('rotation') || 0;
});

modify.on('rotating', function (e) {
    // Set angle attribute to be used on style !
    e.feature.set('rotation', startangle - e.angle);
});

modify.on('select', function(e) {
    draw.setActive(e.features.length == 0);
});

map.addInteraction(modify);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Performance is improved by maintaining a cache of styled scaled icons, and the Transform interaction fits the icons better if the icons are aligned to a polygon which fits inside the original circle.

```js
var debug = true;  // show bounding polygons

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://www.mikenunn.net/data/oak-tree-icon-png-17.png';

var styleCache = {};

function getStyle(img, scaleX, scaleY) {
    var x = Math.round(img.width * scaleX);
    var y = Math.round(img.height * scaleY);
    var key = img.src + ',' + x + ',' + y
    var style = styleCache[key]
    if (!style) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = x;
        canvas.height = y;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, x, y);
        var url = canvas.toDataURL();
        canvas.remove();
        var keys = Object.keys(styleCache);
        if (keys.length >= 100) {
            // delete an old entry to limit the cache size
            delete styleCache[keys[0]];
        }
        var style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
               src: url
            })
        });
        styleCache[key] = style;
    }
    return style;
}

var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
var width = 3;
styles = [
  new ol.style.Style({
   //     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
   //       color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
   //     })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: white,
      width: width + 2
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: blue,
      width: width
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: width * 2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
      })
    }),
    zIndex: Infinity
  })
];

var treeStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
       src: img.src
    })
});

styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var resAdjust = 150 * resolution;
    var rotation = feature.get('rotation');
    if (rotation !== undefined) {

        var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];

        var left = coordinates[0];
        var bottom = coordinates[1];
        var right = coordinates[2];
        var top = coordinates[3];
        var center = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);

        var closest = new ol.geom.LineString([top, bottom]).getClosestPoint(left);
        var dx = closest[0] - left[0];
        var dy = closest[1] - left[1];
        var scaleX = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)/resAdjust;

        var dx = top[0] - center[0];
        var dy = top[1] - center[1];
        var scaleY = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)/resAdjust;
        var rotation = Math.atan2(dx, dy) - Math.PI;

        var treeStyle2 = getStyle(img, scaleX, scaleY);
        treeStyle2.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(center));
        treeStyle2.getImage().setRotation(rotation);
        return debug ? styles.concat([treeStyle2]) : treeStyle2;

    } else if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {

        treeStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
        // get rotation from drawn feature or geometry
        treeStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
        treeStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/resAdjust);
        return treeStyle;

    } else {
       return styles;
    } 
}

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var features = new ol.Collection();

var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false, features: features});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
    })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Circle',
    geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
        var center = coordinates[0];
        var last = coordinates[1];
        var dx = center[0] - last[0];
        var dy = center[1] - last[1];
        var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var rotation = Math.PI - Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        geometry = geometry || new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
        geometry.setCenterAndRadius(center, radius);
        geometry.set('rotation', rotation);
        return geometry;
    },
    style: styleFunction
});

draw.on('drawstart', function () {
    //source.clear();
});

draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
    // move rotation from geometry to drawn feature
    var rotation = evt.feature.getGeometry().get('rotation');
    evt.feature.set('rotation', rotation);
    var geom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(evt.feature.getGeometry(), 4, -rotation);
    evt.feature.setGeometry(geom);
});

map.addInteraction(draw);

var modify = new ol.interaction.Transform({
    features: features,
    translateFeature: false,
    // flip wouldn't be compatible with rotation
    noFlip: true 
});

var startangle = 0;

modify.on('rotatestart', function(e) {
    startangle = e.feature.get('rotation') || 0;
});

modify.on('rotating', function (e) {
    // Set angle attribute to be used on style !
    e.feature.set('rotation', startangle - e.angle);
});

modify.on('select', function(e) {
    draw.setActive(e.features.length == 0);
});

map.addInteraction(modify);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: I think that your solution can help me a lot, thanks!  I insert your code in my file but, I don't know why, now I have a lot, really a lot, of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minX' of undefined` error messages and when I finish to draw the icon the app stop to work well.

Comment: I had only tested using source for the interactions, changing to features causes the same problem for me.  If you change to source the features collection will still be maintained because it's linked to the source.

Comment: Thank you! There were just few little editing to make it work in my code: I had to change `this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: source, ` in `this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            features: this.features, ` and  in the _map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select..)_, i had to change `source: source` in `source: this.source`

Comment: But how I can do to make appear a rectangle instead of a circle? I tried to add in the pointStyle `geometryFunction: ol.interaction.Draw.createRegularPolygon(4),` but it doesn't work

Comment: You would need a custom interaction for that.  See the snippet using one from ol-ext which also handles rotation.

Comment: I don't know why I have this _FloorplanPositioningMap.js:230 Uncaught TypeError: ol.interaction.Transform is not a constructor_   error. I searched a solution on line but I really not found something that solve this error. I hope that I made all the imports in the right way in my index.html?

Comment: did you include `<script src="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Yes I included it. I edited my original post so to add also my index.html file (or anyway the index.html that I edited)

Comment: You shouldn't need to duplicate anything in the body which is already in the head.  Both ol and ol-ext will be the same versions even though in different urls.  Some of the ol-ext stuff does use jquery, but ol.interaction.Transform works without it.

Comment: I solved the  _FloorplanPositioningMap.js:230 Uncaught TypeError: ol.interaction.Transform is not a constructor_  error ! Maybe this solution can be usefull also to someone else: I had to add also in my load.js file: `if (debugMode) {
        addScriptFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/' + olVersion + '/ol-debug.js');
        addScriptFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js');
    } else {
        addScriptFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/' + olVersion + '/ol.js');
        addScriptFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js');
    }`

Comment: Now it works everything, thanks @Mike! I have just to solve one little thing (because i want also to edit my icon without keep aspect ratio), but except that everything is perfect! Thank you very mcuh!

Comment: I have the felling that if the ol.interaction.Draw type is 'Circle' it is only possible to scale the image proportionally (so keeping the aspect ratio)

Comment: If you could change the aspect ratio it wouldn't be a circle, it would be an ellipse.  While you might be able to convert the circle geometry to a polygon to do that, there's another problem: it's not possible to change the aspect ration of icons.  There's a 4 year old change request, but nothing has been done https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/3803

Comment: ahhhh, ok. so it will be no possible to manage that functionality...thank you for letting me know. I want to ask you  just one last thing. Is it normal that when I click on my icon, doesn't appear the little square in the center (it appear only when i make the rotation)? Because would be more intuitive translate the icon grabbing by the center (so using this little rectangle in the middle how happen in the link that you sent to me when the user select "enable scale, enable stretch,  enable rotate, enable translate")

Comment: `translateFeature: false` is the setting you need.  A workaround to changing the aspect ratio of icons would be to dynamically create scaled icons using canvas.  I've added another demo but it's inefficient, sometimes it cannot keep up with the rendering and causes flickering when the map re-renders frequently.  Also changing the geometry to a polygon to allow stretching causes the Transform interaction rectangle to be displayed further away from the icon.  The icon source must also be same origin or CORS enabled.

Comment: mm ok...Anyway thank you very much! You helped me a lot, thanks

Comment: Using a style cache is more efficient and seems to significantly reduce the flicker.  But a cache could potentially use a lot of memory, so it should be limited to slightly more than the maximum number of icons that might be visible at any time.

Comment: Mike you are the best! Thank you very much!